# Replace values instead of varchar into boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

I have different database tables,

Database 1:

Table 1:

```
Id -001(int)

Name -xxx(varchar)

Male -0 (bit)

Female-1 (bit)
```

Database 2:

Table 2:

```
Id -1 (int)

Ca.Name-yyy (varchar)

Gender - M or F (varchar)
```

These are my tables. I want to create insert query from database 2, then i execute to table 1. But I have problem doing this.

how to do this?

Comment: BTW, the column names above are not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO database1.Table1 ( Id, Name, Male, Female )
SELECT id, name, CAST( CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Bit), CAST( CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 0 ELSE 1end as Bit) FROM database2.Table2
```

I think from your posting your going from Table2 to table1, the above should work in that scenario

Comment: It is correct. But when i use 2 values means like 'M' or 'B' Then 1 Else 0. When i use this i get error or operator not using here. how to use it?

Comment: You cannot add an or into a case, in that case you would do

CAST( CASE gender 
WHEN 'M' THEN 1
WHEN 'B' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as Bit)

Keep adding WHEN clauses for any additional values

Answer (score 2):

You can execute `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement and use `CASE` to check if the user is `Male or Female`.

```
INSERT  INTO dbase2.dbo.Table2(ID, Name, Gender)
SELECT  ID, Name,
        CASE WHEN Male = 1 THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END Gender
FROM    dbase1.dbo.Table1
```

Comment: select 'Insert into Table2(Id,Name,Male,Female)values('+
    Case when Gender='M' THEN 0 Else 'F'+')' END Gender from Table1. This is my query. I get error "Coversion failed varchar to int"

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you generating a dynamic query?

Comment: You answered, database 2 have field Gender and database 1 have only Male and female fields. You totally changed into opposite. Also i get error.

Comment: what do you mean opposite, the schema is based on your question. what the query does is it insert all records from database 1 table 1 into database2 table2. but before inserting it it test if the gender from table 1 is male or female. can you update your statement or make your example in tabular format.